# How to read multi-channel 16-bit-per-channel images in Python without using OpenCV library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, png, python-imaging-library

You can download a multi-channel, 16-bit png file from [here](http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png) (shown below). I have tried multiple Python packages for reading this multi-channel 16-bit-per-channel image. But none work, and if they do somehow they transform the images (scaling etc). I tried using `imageio`, `PIL.Image`, `scipy.ndimage.imread` and a couple more. It seems that they all can read single-channel 16-bit pngs properly but convert the multi-channel images into 8-bit-per-channel. For instance, [this](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/146) is a GitHub issue thst indicates `imageio` cannot read **multi-channel** 16-bit images. Another issue ([here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1888))  for Pillow seems to say the same thing.

So I wonder, does anyone know how can I read multi-channel, 16-bit png files in Python without using OpenCV package properly? Feel free to offer solutions from other packages that I didn't mention anything about here.

[image]

Comment: another imageio issue:https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/204

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1 - Split into channels with ImageMagick**

You could use **ImageMagick** (it is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows) at the command line.

For example, this will separate your 16-bit 3-channel PNG into its constituent channels that you can then process individually in Pillow:

```
magick input.png -separate channel-$d.png
```

Now there are 3 separate channels:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     2276  1 Apr 16:47 channel-2.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     3389  1 Apr 16:47 channel-1.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     2277  1 Apr 16:47 channel-0.png
```

and they are each 16-bit, single channel images that Pillow can open:

```
magick identify channel-*
```

**Sample Output**

```
channel-0.png PNG 600x600 600x600+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 2277B 0.000u 0:00.000
channel-1.png PNG 600x600 600x600+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 3389B 0.000u 0:00.000
channel-2.png PNG 600x600 600x600+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 2276B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

If you are using **ImageMagick** v6, replace `magick` with `convert` and replace `magick identify` with plain `identify`.

---

**Option 2 - Split into channels with NetPBM**

As an alternative to **ImageMagick**, you could use the much lighter weight NetPBM tools to do the same thing:

```
pngtopam < rainbow.png | pamchannel - 0 -tupletype GRAYSCALE > channel-0.pam
pngtopam < rainbow.png | pamchannel - 1 -tupletype GRAYSCALE > channel-1.pam
pngtopam < rainbow.png | pamchannel - 2 -tupletype GRAYSCALE > channel-2.pam
```

Pillow can then open the PAM files.

---

**Option 3 - Use PyVips**

As an alternative, you could use the extremely fast, memory-efficient `pyvips` to process your images. Here is an example from the [documentation](https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use) that:

- crops 100 pixels off each side
- shrinks an image by 10% with bilinear interpolation
- sharpens with a convolution and re-saves the image.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import sys
import pyvips

im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access='sequential')
im = im.crop(100, 100, im.width - 200, im.height - 200)
im = im.reduce(1.0 / 0.9, 1.0 / 0.9, kernel='linear')
mask = pyvips.Image.new_from_array([[-1, -1,  -1], 
                                    [-1,  16, -1], 
                                    [-1, -1,  -1]], scale=8)
im = im.conv(mask, precision='integer')
im.write_to_file("result.png")
```

The result is 16-bit like the input image:

```
identify result.png
result.png PNG 360x360 360x360+0+0 16-bit sRGB 2900B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

As you can see it is still 16-bit, and trimming 100px off each side results in 600px becoming 400px and then the 10% reduction makes that into 360px.

---

**Option 4 - Convert to TIFF and use PyLibTiff**

A fourth option, if the number of files is an issue, might be to convert your images to TIFF with **ImageMagick**

```
convert input.png output.tif
```

and they retain their 16-bit resolution, and you process them with PyLibTiff as shown [here](http://tjelvarolsson.com/blog/saving-16bit-tiff-files-using-python/).

---

**Option 5 - Multi-image TIFF processed as ImageSequence**

A fifth option, could be to split your PNG files into their constituent channel and store them as a multi-image TIFF, i.e. with Red as the first image in the sequence, green as the second and blue as the third. This means there is no increase in he number of files and also you can store more than 3 channels per file - you mentioned 5 channels somewhere in your comments:

```
convert input.png -separate multiimage.tif
```

Check there are now 3 images, each 16-bit, but all in the same, single file:

```
identify multiimage.tif
multiimage.tif[0] TIFF 600x600 600x600+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 10870B 0.000u 0:00.000
multiimage.tif[1] TIFF 600x600 600x600+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 10870B 0.000u 0:00.000
multiimage.tif[2] TIFF 600x600 600x600+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 10870B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Then process them as an image sequence:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open("multiimage.tif")

index = 1
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    print(index)
    index = index + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it would be better to not add another layer of complexity to the problem. Being able to import the image directly in Python would be much easier than making many files on the disk. What if the image has `5` channels or more? In my case, I have millions of images and using `magick` will multiply this number by `3`.

Comment: Not sure I see that argument, if you have 2 million images, you might as well have 6 million. Both are a lot! I hope you will use **GNU Parallel** to process them all in order to benefit from multiple cores. In the meantime, please look at my updated answer and consider using `pyvips`.

Comment: The problem with the last 2 options is that they all distort the original image and apply some sort of transformation. For my applications, this totally destroys my data and makes it unusable for me. I need a very straight-forward method to do that but it seems that almost none of the packages in Python (except CV2) offer this capability in a straight-forward manner, as of now.

Comment: Could you take a moment to share your thoughts on Options 1-3 please? I am not a Python user myself and I'd like to know the shortcomings of my methods so I can be more useful in future!

Comment: For my previous comment, I meant the last 3 answer not 2. For 1-2 the problem is that they triple the IO overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found out that imageio can do the job:

```
img = imageio.imread('path/to/img', format='PNG-FI')
```

With this option you can read and write multi-channel 16-bit png images (by default imageio uses `PNG-PIL` as format for reading png files). This works for png images, but changing the `format` can probably help when dealing with other image types ([here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html) a full list of available imageio formats).

To use this format you may need to install the FreeImage plugin as shown in the [documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_png-fi.html).